# Let $X$ be a metric space and $E\subset X$. Prove that $E\setminus \partial E$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a metric space and $E\subset X$. We say that $x\in X$ is a boundary point of $E$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point in $E$ and at least one point in $E^c$. The set of all boundary points of $E$ is denoted $\partial E$.

Prove that $E\setminus \partial E$ is open.

This is my attempt:
Assume that $x\in E\setminus \partial E$ and we need to show that there exists an open ball centered at $x$ that is completely contained in $E\setminus \partial E$.

Since $x\notin \partial E$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ that contains either only points in $E$ or only points in $E^c$.
We know that $x$ can't have a neighborhood that contains points only from $E^c$,because x is in E. With that I know half of the answer, but how can I prove that this neighborhood doesn't contain any points from ∂E?

Comment: I guess it's invalid to automatically assume that $U$ contains only points in $E$.

Comment: You can't assume without loss of generality that $U$ contains only points from $E$. You know there is a neighborhood which contains only points from $E$ or only points from $E^c$. The point is to show that the second option is impossible. And that's easy, because any neighborhood will contain the point $x$ itself.

Comment: @Mark Is it okay if I add: assume there exists some $y \in U$ such that $y \in E^c$. Since $U$ is open, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that the ball $B(y, \epsilon)$ is contained in $U$. But then $B(y, \epsilon)$ contains no points in $E$, contradicting the fact that $U$ contains at least one point in $E$. Therefore, $U$ cannot contain any points in $E^c$, and thus $U \subseteq E$.

Comment: @MathEnthusiast No. $B(y,\epsilon)$ not containing any points in $E$ doesn't mean that the larger set $U$ doesn't contain them. There are many neighborhoods of $x$ which contain points from both $E$ and $E^c$. (for example, take $U=X$) So you can't prove such a thing for a general neighborhood. But as I said, you know that $x$ has some neighborhood which only contains points from one of $E$ or $E^c$. But it's trivial that $x$ can't have a neighborhood which contains only points from $E^c$, because $x$ itself is not in $E^c$. Thus it must have a neighborhood which contains only points from $E$.

Comment: (I continue my previous comment) And then just explain why this chosen neighborhood $U$ is contained in $E\setminus\partial{E}$. You know it is contained in $E$, so just explain why it doesn't contain any points from $\partial{E}$.

Comment: The assertion is false. Think of the rationals in the real line

Comment: @ArcticChar What is false exactly? In your example, the set $E\setminus\partial E$ is empty, and so trivially open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Mark Yes indeed, that's a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\overline{E}^c\subseteq E^c$. Then:
$$E/\partial E=E\cap(\overline{E}\cap(E^o)^c)^c=E\cap (\overline{E}^c\cup E^o)=E\cap E^o$$